# Angular 2 Printing POS receipts

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

My Angular 2 project requires printing POS related receipts on paper. 
Can anyone suggest, what is the standard way for printing receipts for web app.

Currently, I am using Angular 2 as client side technology calling web services for manipulating data.

Should it be done client side(using browser) or server Side ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how did u resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done in the client side itself using the print() method

```
<button (click)="printMe()" > Print </button>
```

The method as

```
printMe(){
   window.print();
}
```

**Note : This method will print what ever visible on the screen.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Aravind, Is it the accepted way to print POS receipts ? How to make the paper cut according to the height of the receipt ? ps. the height of the receipt can be dynamic.

Comment: paper cut how can you do that? manual work only. else you should define the size of the paper

Comment: Thanks Aravind, my actual problem was related to **configuration** :- Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers >> Epson tm-t81 receipt printer>> right click "Printer Preferences" >> 
Document Settings >> Paper Source >> Page[Feed, Cut]